# numpy: row wise product of a 2-D matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I want to perform a row-wise multiplication of a 2-D matrix, e.g. obtain with the 2-D array `x`

```
>>> x = np.column_stack((np.ones(10), np.arange(1,11)))
>>> x
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  7.],
       [ 1.,  8.],
       [ 1.,  9.],
       [ 1., 10.]])
```

an array with 1 to 10. I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070493/numpy-2-d-3-d-matrix-row-wise-multiplication) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155503/element-wise-product-of-two-2-d-lists) that I could use `np.multiply()` using each column of my array as inputs. I want, however, to have something generalizable for 2-D arrays with more than two columns. My goal is to use as inputs the matrix/array itself and obtain the row-wise product of all columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.multiply.reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) to apply `np.multiply` along the second axis reducing its dimension by `1`:

```
np.multiply.reduce(x, axis=1)
# array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.])
```

---

Which generalises to any `2d` shaped array:

```
x = np.arange(30).reshape((-1, 3))

array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26],
       [27, 28, 29]])

np.multiply.reduce(x, axis=1)
# array([    0,    60,   336,   990,  2184,  4080,  6840, 10626, 15600, 21924])
```

Comment: thank so much! how does that differ from the answer from Dev Khadka below? They perform equally in cpu time but visually the output seems different.

Comment: Both `np.multiply.reduce` and `np.prod` should perform just as well @bruno

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

is this what you wanted

```py
x = np.column_stack((np.ones(10), np.arange(1,11)))
np.prod(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

**Output**

```
array([[ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 5.],
       [ 6.],
       [ 7.],
       [ 8.],
       [ 9.],
       [10.]])
```

Comment: How does that differ from the answer below from yatu? Both of your answers perform equally in CPU time...

Comment: np.multiply is an "ufunc" to multiply two array, using reduce performs multiplication with same array repeatedly until you get single value. np.prod is convenience function which may be using np.multiply internally